# What is the ZSH equivalent of 'expr'?

Tags: shell, zsh

The expr utility evaluates an expression and writes the result on standard output.

What is the canonical ZSH way to evaluate an expression, and print the result?

Solution:

I believe the answer is to use eval:

For example:

```
% eval 'export FOO=baz'
% echo $FOO
baz
```

I also found a similar Superuser question ["zsh run a command stored in a variable?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665172/zsh-run-a-command-stored-in-a-variable)

Comment: `expr` is a standalone command and thus can also be called from zsh. `eval` is **not** the same as `expr`. `eval` reads arguments as input to the shell and executes them in the context of the current shell process. While `eval` just evaluates certain expressions (see `man 1 expr` for more info) which are not dependant on the shell, although some expressions may look similar

Comment: I wish to _reads arguments as input to the shell and execute them in the context of the current shell process_ . Perhaps I should rephrase my question and answer. Any input from you is welcomed.

Comment: Whether you need to rephrase your question depends on what you want to achieve. If you want to run a command from a variable `eval` is the way to go and the question and answer can already be found in the question you linked. If you want to evaluate expressions (where expressions are more or less of the arithmetic kind) `expr` or some zsh equivalent may be better suited.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As `expr` is just a stand-alone command it can be used with `zsh` just like any other command, although many operators may need to be escaped or quoted:

```
% expr 7 * 2
expr: syntax error
% expr 7 '*' 2
14
% expr 8 < 9
zsh: no such file or directory: 
% expr 8 \< 9
1
```

If you want to only use zsh builtins there is no single catch all alternative.

Most arithmetic expressions can be handled with `echo $(( exp ))`

```
% echo $(( 7 * 2 ))
14
% echo $(( 8 < 9 ))
1
```

Some of the string operations can be replaced with parameter expansions. (Note that `expr` counts positions from 1, while `zsh` starts with 0)

```
% str='hello world'
% expr substr $str 4 5
lo wo
% echo ${str:3:5}
lo wo
% expr length $str
11
% echo $#str
11
```